# RTNETLINK answers: Device or resource busy

Tags: bash, networking, dns, virtual-machine

I was trying to create a new instance of a network interface to set DNS Server configuration on it.
When I run this command:

```
ip link set enp1s0 name ens33 && ip link set ens33 up
```

then terminal will give me this message:

```
RTNETLINK answers: Device or resource busy
```

Answer (score 11):

set the interface **down** before renaming , Try below

```
ip link set down enp1s0 && ip link set enp1s0 name ens33 && ip link set up ens33
```

Now if config will show interface with name ens33